# Fortran 90 Reading in Characters and Integers from a data file

Tags: arrays, integer, fortran, character

Ok, so In my program I'm supposed to take in the name of the data file from the user than open it and read the contents. But when I open and read it all that characters just end up being ****** and all the integers end up being 0. IDK if it's how I'm reading in the file or the format?

The file will contain something like this: (where the number of cities is the first number)

```
4 
SanDiego 
0 
350 
900 
1100 
Phoenix 
350 
0 
560 
604 
Denver 
900 
560 
0 
389 
Dallas 
1100 
604 
389 
0
```

So far my code is this where first I take in the first number than on every firstnumber * I + I pass is supposed to go into the character array city. Now the rest of the numbers I am storing into a integer array, but really want it into a integer matrix called d_table but I couldn't think of a way to do that immediately on the read.

```
PROGRAM p4

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: number, status, I, J, K, permutation = 0, distance = 0, distance = 999999
CHARACTER(50) :: filename  ! Filenames longer than 50 are truncated
CHARACTER(20), DIMENSION(10) :: city
INTEGER, DIMENSION(100) :: temp
INTEGER, DIMENSION(10,10) :: d_table
INTEGER, DIMENSION(10) :: path, best_path

WRITE (*, '(1x,A)', ADVANCE="NO") "Enter filename:  "
READ *, filename

! Open the file we created and read the contents

OPEN(UNIT=15, FILE=filename, STATUS="OLD", ACTION="READ",&
     IOSTAT=status)
IF(status /= 0) THEN
    PRINT *, "ERROR, could not open file for reading."
    STOP
END IF

READ (UNIT=15, FMT = 100, IOSTAT=status) number
J = 0
K = 0
DO I = 0, number*number
    IF(I == J*number+J) THEN
        READ (UNIT=15, FMT = 200, IOSTAT=status) city(J)
        J = J + 1
    ELSE
        READ (UNIT=15, FMT = 100, IOSTAT=status) temp(K)
        K = K + 1
    END IF
END DO
K = 0
DO I = 0, number
    DO J = 0, number
        d_table(I,J) = temp(K)
        K = K + 1
    END DO
END DO
100 FORMAT(I6)
200 FORMAT (A)
END PROGRAM p4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
DO I = 0, number*number
```

looks wonky to me; the loop will be executed 17 times.  Surely you want to read `number` groups of 5 lines, each group being one city name followed by four integers ?  That would be a good case for a little loop nest, something like

```
do ix = 1, number
   read(15,*) city(ix)
   do jx = 1, 4
      read(15,*) d_table(ix,jx)
   end do
end do
```

Given such a simple input file format there's no need to bother with format statements, list-directed input will work just fine.

I can't see the point of all the index arithmetic the code is doing, perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: When I use WRITE (*, '("Got the number ",I6)') number to print the number I get 0 and when I print the city with 2000 FORMAT (A) I get a blank for the first city

Comment: Also, when I replace READ (UNIT=15, FMT = 100, IOSTAT=status) number with read(15,*) number I get unexpected character in integer value